# specified cast is not valid

Tags: sql-server, c#

I have a table and I wrote a class to initialize it.here is some part of class.

```
this.semester = new TSemester((short)v[0]);
this.course = (int)v[1];
this.xGroup = (byte)v[2];
this.xType = (byte)v[3];
this.subject = (int)v[4];
this.form = (byte)v[5];
this.stdCount = (int)v[6];
this.point = (int)v[7];
this.pointMax = (int)v[8];
this.badCount = (int)v[9];
this.cDate = new TDate((int)v[10]);
this.remark = (string)v[11];
this.options = (int)v[12];
```

when i try to fill the class with a query.. in line:*this.xGroup = (byte)v[2];* i have error *specified cast is not valid*
 query is:

```
select Semester,0,0,0,Subject,0,sum(StdCount),avg(point) 
,avg(pointMax),sum(badcount),13940101,'',0 from EvlClass inner join members 
on members.srl = Subject where Semester = 13951 and XType=1 and Subject 
in(select Srl from Members where Unit in (1101))group by 
unit,Semester,Subject
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is returning an integer literal of zero so it can't be cast as byte directly in the app code. You'll need to either return byte literal `0x00`, `CAST(0 AS tinyint)`, or convert the integer value to byte in your code using `Convert.ToByte((Int32)v[2]);`. Same with the other byte columns.